# Adding an API definition manually in swagger using springfox

Tags: swagger, springfox

I am using `springfox` for generating Swagger API documentation for REST APIs exposed by a `spring boot` application.

I need to add documentation for an API manually for which there is no `REST controller`, technically. How can I manually add to the Swagger API documentation? I want to do it once from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it using [plugins](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#plugins) mechanism. Create ApiListingScannerPlugin to dynamic added ApiDescription and OperationModelsProviderPlugin to dynamic added Definitions